# Problema con el módulo google.cloud en python

Tags: python, sql, google-bigquery

recientemente he realizado el micro curso de Kaggle sobre introducción a SQL. Mi problema surge cuando voy a cargar en un notebook de Jupyter el siguiente módulo:

```
from google.cloud import bigquery
```

El problema es que al ir a cargarlo me dice que no existe a pesar de que ya lo he instalado con la orden:

```
pip install --upgrade google-cloud-bigquery
```

Muchas gracias de antemano